# How are data packets handled if too many are sent

Tags: networking

I understand about DOS and DDOS attacks, but what I am asking is how a network handles being sent more packets than its connection allows

so for example

[Service A]----------[ISP]-----------[Me]

if service A's internet connection allows him to upload 8mb/ps and my connection allows me to download 1mb/ps , what happens if he sends me slightly more than I can handle, obviously not 8mb, but maybe 1.01?

Is there some sort of queueing system or is the amount of packets sent determined by the sender based on latency?

Thanks

Comment: The packets are dropped.  This is the reason DOS and DDOS attacks are effective.  Are you sure you actually understand those attacks, this question itself, seems to indicate you don't actually understand.  These attacks send so many packets, the server depends all its processing power to process them, on top of filling the "pipe" with garbage data.  Which is the reason these attacks are hard to prevent, once they happen, they are pretty simple to deal with in an broad overview.

Comment: Also note that most DOS and DDOS attacks historyically do not attempt to saturate bandwidth, but instead target the service at the TCP layer or higher. its a lot easier to take a service offline than it is to perpetually saturate the bandwidth.

Comment: Question is poorly written. What I mean is how do services know how to not send too many packets. e.g. netflix. When you're streaming how does it know how many packets you can handle without your internet crashing. If you chose to watch in HD on netflix with internet that cannot handle it, it will send you the HD packets, however it will be constantly buffering, why doesn't you're internet crash if its being sent too many? Or are they sending them based on your speed

Comment: @GarethS - *So improve the question.....*  How Netflix does it is their secret sauce....Netflix has not buffered HD content for awhile now, they attempt to determine if you can handle it, then only then proceed with the HD content.

Answer (score 0):

No, for a couple reasons.

1. the Queuing system would have to occur upstream far enough that the queue could accept traffic, so there would have to be free bandwidth there. That means its ISP-tier equipment. It would likely be quite expensive.
2. TCP uses windowing protocols to perform flow control and error correction. these mechanisms rely on data being recieved in a timely fashion. a queue that took too long to flush might trigger your hosts to request resends on packets that have been sent but are waiting in queue, causing more traffic and longer lines, which woudl spiral into devastation.
3. There are better architechures for dealing with large demand spikes for resources, involving CDNs and co-locality, meshed network architechures, etc.

Edit:
based on your comment, the answer you are looking for is [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) [Flow and Concestion Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_%28data%29). TCP uses a "sliding window" approach to flow control. When a server is sending you a stream, TCP will negotiate a window interval, and every X packets they send to you, you must send one back to them. they will not send further packets until you do. if everything is going great, a wide windows is better because it doesn't wait for you to respond as often, but if you delay in responding, the server will lower the interval, so you must in effect say "yeah, I got that". Its a lot like reading your CC number to someone over the phone. you say four numbers, and wait for them to say "ok" or somthing before saying the next four numbers. if they don't say ok, you wait a little until they do.